# Unable to unserialize on Sales -> Order page

Tags: unserialize

after upgrading the theme I can not access the sales -> order page any more with the following error.
I disabled all third party extensions to solve possible conflict without success.
I am using Magento 2.4

I'd appreciate any help.
This is the error

> {"0":"Unable to unserialize value.","1":"#1
> Magento\Ui\Model\Bookmark->getConfig() called at
> [vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Bookmark.php:81]\n#2
> Magento\Ui\Component\Bookmark->prepare() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:164]\n#3
> Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent()
> called at
> ...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like one of the entries in your ui_bookmark table contains a non JSON config value. You could try finding the culprit there by checking the entries for your user_id.

Alternatively you can empty the ui_bookmark table and see if that resolves the issue.